# how i can fix this elephant.io connection probelm

Tags: php, socket.io, codeigniter-3

My client interconnection
socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000', { transports : ['websocket'] });

Before adding transport, it was not connecting on the client side
transports : ['websocket'] fixed after adding.

now i am trying to connect with elephant.io

but I am getting error as below

> Message: An error occurred while trying to establish a connection to
> the server Filename:
> C:\AppServ\www\test\vendor\wisembly\elephant.io\src\Engine\SocketIO\Version1X.php
> Line Number: 187
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File:
> C:\AppServ\www\test\vendor\wisembly\elephant.io\src\Engine\SocketIO\Version1X.php
> Line: 48 Function: handshake
>
> File: C:\AppServ\www\test\vendor\wisembly\elephant.io\src\Client.php
> Line: 60 Function: connect
>
> File:
> C:\AppServ\www\test\application\controllers\Messages_controller.php
> Line: 33 Function: initialize
>
> File: C:\AppServ\www\test\index.php Line: 315 Function: require_once

Versin2x using.

```
$options = [
    'context' => [
        'ssl' => [
            'verify_peer' => false,
            'verify_peer_name' => false
        ]
    ]
];

$client = new Client(new Version2X('http://localhost:3000',$options));
$client->initialize();
```

Could I be experiencing an error because localhost does not have ssl?
or could it be an error from file_get_content.

I can't find a solution anymore, I will be very grateful to anyone who can help

Framework : codeigniter 3x

Answer (score 0):

I had a same problem, I am using node as server and elephant.io for connecting client to server.

I changed my socket version in package.json file from 3.0.0 to 2.2.0 and solved it. if it will help you can try.

elephant io will not work more with version 3 or more.

**UPDATED:**

I find out solution in github for socket connetion with more than version 3.

Here is it.

https://github.com/tohenk/elephant.io

Comment: Linking to the [README](https://github.com/Wisembly/elephant.io/blob/master/README.md) on GitHub could be helpful for the OP. It shows that they only support up to 2.x with their built in engines.

Comment: Is there any alternative for elephant.io ?

Comment: @hiren-viradia Check out pusher.com or socket.io directly.